# SQL join by limiting one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that looks like this

```
TABLE1
-------------------------------
Col1    Col2   Col3
------------------------------
foo     1       83433
bar     2       33333



TABLE2
-------------------------------
Col1    Col2   Col3       Col4
------------------------------
ksd     a       xxxx     1
asx     b       yyyy     2
....
1 million rows.
```

What I'm trying to do is to join `Col2` of `Table1` with `Col4` of `Table2`
and but before joining them I'd like to limit only top 1000 of `Table2`.
How can I achieve that?

Here is my current attempt that doesn't work

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON T1.Col2 = T2.Col4 (LIMIT 1000)
```

Comment: Top 1000 according to what ordering?  If you don't order the rows the set of rows you will get back is undefined -- the database can provide any 1000 rows in the table.  This could be the 1000 most recently inserted, the 1000 least recently inserted, the 1000 rows that appear first on disk, or any other criteria the database server wants.  It could even change between different versions of the same database server software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it in a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM TABLE1 T1 JOIN
     (select T2.*
      from TABLE2 T2
      limit 1000
     ) T2
ON T1.Col2 = T2.Col4;
```

Note that `limit` without an `order by` does not guarantee which rows are returned.  Hence, I would expect an `order by` in this case.